# Connection with public API

Tags: java, javafx

This is my second project ever in javaFX so I am stuck with no result from connection. I tried to connect to URL and not very sure if I am doing it right.
In one project which I found on the net, there is connection in one class, and the rest of the code in controller, so I writen in that way, and now I get just my GUI without any result from `System.out.println`.
But, when I put my code in class `Main`, I get all the result.
I would like to have connection in one class and controller in other, so, please tell me what did I do wrong in my code so far.

This is controller:

```
package pretvaracValuta;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class PretvaracController implements Initializable {

    private URLconnection uc;

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        uc = new URLconnection();
    }


    public void connection() {
        HttpURLConnection conn = uc.urlConnect();

        try {   

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Broj tečajnice = "+ responseCode);
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);

                System.out.println(response.toString());
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection();

    }
}
```

This is URLconnection class:

```
package pretvaracValuta;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class URLconnection {

public HttpURLConnection urlConnect() {

    try {   

        URL obj = new URL("http://api.hnb.hr/");

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        return con;
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: How is the `connection` method invoked? Furthermore do you intend to provoke a `StackOverflowError`? (This is what is done with `connection()` unless an exception is thrown that is not caught.)

Comment: Oh, that was my last try to run this method. With or withou it, its not getting any data.

Comment: I figured out that I need to put connection() method into initializable to start. Didnt know that earlier. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel if it already exists? Try using [`Unirest`](http://unirest.io/java.html)

```
System.out.println( Unirest.get( "http://api.hnb.hr/" )
                           .asJson()
                           .getBody()
                           .toString()
);
```

Note, `http://api.hnb.hr/` is returning a website page view. Maybe try requesting the actual API like `http://api.hnb.hr/tecajn/v1`.

[Here is a link to the Maven dependency.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java/1.4.9)

Comment: One more dependency... When twenty line of code do the job.

Comment: @Aubin because at some point, he'd need a JSON library either way, why make something more complex that it needs to be